# Simple 5 Color - Picker, Get hex value for text in form

Tags: javascript, c#, html

Hello all I am trying to implement a very simple color picker. I do not need a full pallet of colors. I have 5. Along with some JavaScript.

I want to get the value in hex of selected color and have it inserted in the color field of the form.

Here is what I have:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Color, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Color, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = "", @Id = "ColorPicker" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Color, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>

<div class="btn-group" style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <ul class="fc-color-picker" id="color-chooser">
        <li><a id="color" class="text-primary" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
        <li><a id="color" class="text-warning" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
        <li><a id="color" class="text-success" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
        <li><a id="color" class="text-danger" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
        <li><a class="text-muted" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript. It does turn the textbox the color, but I want to save the hex value to the database. Currently the Textbox displays `[object Object]` when selecting a color. How can I script this to get the hex color for my data field.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    var currColor = '#3c8dbc' //Red by default
    // Color chooser button
    $('#color-chooser > li > a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        // Save color
        currColor = $(this).css('color')
        // Add color effect to button
        $('#ColorPicker').css({
            'background-color': currColor,
            'border-color': currColor,
        })
        
        $('#ColorPicker').val({
            currColor
        })

    })
})
```

UPDATE:

Adding this instead of the `$('ColorPicker').val` Works but changes all the text fields..

```
$("input:text").val(currColor);
```